# How to print a selection of a PDF document: Safari on Mac using MS Word

Tags: safari, ms-office, pdf, printing

I’m using Safari on Big Sur, and need to capture a small section of a document to send off to someone. In Safari you cannot print just a selection of a page. Suggestions on how to do this?

Answer (score 1):

- Take a screenshot of the part you want to share using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Cmd</kbd><kbd>4</kbd> (puts it into the clipboard)
- Create a new mail to someone and paste the picture

Answer (score 0):

I have a MS 365 subscription and managed find a solution using MSWord. In Safari I exported the entire document to PDF, then opened the PDF in Word. I was then able to select exactly the section I needed and print it to PDF.

nohillside's answer would work for me if my selection didn't cross the border between pages, which has a header and a footer that I don't want to send in the PDF.